# Excel Range less clumsy

Tags: vba, excel

As an old dog (age 73) learning new (Excel VBA) tricks, I am reasonably happy with putting together the code below. But I think it could be cleaner. How would you have coded it?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()  
    Dim lastRow As Long     'last row with data  
    Dim thisDate As Double  'start timestamp  
    thisDate = Now()  
With Sheets("Pressure Log")  
    lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'populate next row with date/time  
    .Range("B" & lastRow + 1 & ":G" & lastRow + 1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous  
    .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1) = Format(thisDate, "dddd")  
    .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 1) = Format(thisDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")  
    .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 2) = Format(thisDate, "hh:mm AM/PM")  
    .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1, 3).Select 'position for data  
End With  
End Sub
```

Comment: Cross post from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683704/excel-range-less-clumsy

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @Toby Speight okay. I did receive terrific responses so I am fine with removing this. How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly formatting and indenting code is always a good start.

Using `Option Explicit` at the top of every module is a must. You may already do this, just thought I would mention it.

You declare `thisDate` as a `Double` but you use it as a `Date`. Declare it as a `Date`.

Make your life a little easier and set a range to the start of your new row instead of calling a calculated range. Example below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()  
    Dim lastRow As Long     'last row with data  
    Dim thisDate As Date  'start timestamp  
    Dim entryRange as Range
    thisDate = Now()  
    With Sheets("Pressure Log")  
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'populate next row with date/time  
        Set entryRange = .Range("B" & lastRow+1) ` There are other ways of doing this too.   
    End With  
    entryRange.resize(1, 6).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous  ' Yes, could do this in a With block as well.
    entryRange.Value = Format(thisDate, "dddd")  
    entryRange.Offset(, 1).Value = Format(thisDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")  
    entryRange.Offset(, 2) = Format(thisDate, "hh:mm AM/PM")  
    entryRange.Offset(, 3).Select 'position for data  
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you  AJD "Properly formatting and indenting code is always a good start  ." Agreed. My script code is indented but I have trouble with this forum's code block.

Comment: thank you  @AJD "Properly formatting and indenting code is always a good start  ." Agreed. My script code is indented but I have trouble with this forum's code block. (as is trying to line break in this comment)  "Using Option Explicit at the top of every module is a must. " I understood the concept, but thought that Option Explicit was once for the entire workbook so I did not know where to put it. Now I know. Thank you. "You declare thisDate as a Double but you use it as a Date. Declare it as a Date." I thought Date was a method, not a type as well. Will make the change

Comment: " Set entryRange = .Range("B" & lastRow+1) ` There are other ways of doing this too." I gather you recommend this as the better alternative. What might be some of the other ways?

Comment: @grNadpa: `Set entryRange = .Range("B" & lastRow).Offset(1,0)` is an easy alternative. You could also use `.Cells(lastRow+1,2)` (not preferable because `Cells` is relative to a range and which cells are selected can be confused if you change the base range). In some cases, just comes down to personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Another `With` statement would make the code easier to read.

> ```
> With Sheets("Pressure Log")
>     lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'populate next row with date/time
>     .Range("B" & lastRow + 1 & ":G" & lastRow + 1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
>     With .Range("B" & lastRow)
>         .Offset(1) = Format(thisDate, "dddd")
>         .Offset(1, 1) = Format(thisDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
>         .Offset(1, 2) = Format(thisDate, "hh:mm AM/PM")
>         .Offset(1, 3).Select                      'position for data
>     End With
> End With
> ```

It is better to format entire columns and rows.  These reduces the file size by combining multiple css rules.

There are many way to skin this cat. For variety I set a range variable ( newRow ) to the next empty row.  This allows me to uses ranges relative to the new row.

```
Dim newRow As Range
With Worksheets("Pressure Log")
    Set newRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
    newRow.Range("B1:G1").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    newRow.Range("B1:D1").Value = Now
    .Columns("C").NumberFormat = "ddd"
    .Columns("D").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    .Columns("E").NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
    .Columns("C:G").AutoFit
    newRow.Columns("E").Select
End With
```

With this setup we can copy all the formats from the row above except NumberFormats by using `Range().FillDown`.

> ```
>  newRow.FillDown
> ```

Alternately, we could copy all the formats from the row above like this:

> ```
> newRow.Offset(-1).Copy
> newRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
> Application.CutCopyMode = False
> ```

Your code is pretty solid but if you truly want to learn Excel VBA I would start by watching this series:  [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&index=1&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

You should also use [Rubberduck VBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/).  It is a free add-in with many features to help you write better code.  The code formatter alone is invaluable.

Last but not least start answering questions on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com).  This will give you exposure to questions that you would never think to ask and solutions that you didn't know where possible.

Comment: Advice on the last suggestion ("Last but not least start answering questions on StackOverflow.") - while providing good exposure it will also open you up to criticism, especially as you learn how to provide a good answer. A thick skin and not taking anything as personal helps weather the early attempts!

Comment: @AJD I agree.  I have my share of callouses.   But I improved more in the 2 years of SO than I did in the previous 6 years.

Comment: @TinMan This is precisely the thorough comment I was hoping for. Thank you. As far as answering questions, I think that may be a bit premature. But I certainly intend to make the effort to read the responses to other questions in this forum

Comment: @grNadpa, Since you're new to Code Review: It's customary to "thank" someone for a contribution that answers your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the Answer. This also lets others with a similar question know when something helped/worked. Later, when you've accumulated reputation (site points) you'll also be able to upvote questions, comments and proposed answers you find useful/helpful. Enjoy!

Comment: @grNadpa I'm glad that it helps.